# Is it possible to change Android targetSdkVersion after release?

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I have built a mobile app by using React Native and published to google play store few days ago. I am trying to change targetSdkVersion to 27 from current version which is 28. I wonder this is possible even though I have already published to play store.

[image: Current version]

Current version is like this and I am trying to change these like below.

```
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
minSdkVersion 16
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
supportLibVersion "27.0.3"
```

Comment: I think, it's impossible 'cause the variants are all static variables at compile time.

Comment: downgrade wont be possible in case of targetSdkversion i believe

Comment: You can but you will have to up your app version and publish new apk/bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's not possible to update the sdkversion for the same build which you already uploaded on PlayStore.

```
To resolve your problem,follow the below steps-

1. You can update the SDK verison.

2. Upgrade the versionCode.

3. Now Upload the new build on playstore.
```

Answer (score 0):

**No, It's not possible.** You need to give a new update of your app with an updated target SDK and version code.